# I have a python Issue with unicode

Tags: python, unicode

I have a dictionary in a specific file, when I try to  run it from other file importing it:

```
import resultado
print ( resultado.dic["10101027"])
```

I have the following error:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xba in position 38: invalid start byte

resultado file:

dic = {

"10101027":"UNIDAD EDUCATIVA DISTRITAL ANTONIO ORNESBARRIO SAN JOSE COTIZA FRENTE CALLE LOS EUCALIPTUS. DERECHA ESCALERA SAN MARCOS. IZQUIERDA ESCALERA SAN JUDA FRENTE AL PARQUE ANDRES GALARRAGA EDIFICIO",
"10101001":"UNIDAD EDUCATIVA DISTRITAL MADARIAGASECTOR ALTAGRACIA DERECHA CALLE CONCORDIA. IZQUIERDA CALLE DELICIAS. FRENTE CALLE DELICIAS A CONCORDIA AL FRENTE COLEGIO BELUTINI CASA",
"10101002":"UNIDAD EDUCATIVA SANTA BARBARASECTOR SANTA BARBARA DERECHA CALLE PARAISO. IZQUIERDA CALLE DOCTOR GONZALEZ. FRENTE CALLE PARAISO FRENTE ESQUINAS DOCTOR GONZALEZ A PARAISO EDIFICIO",
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The message seems pretty clear, at least with respect to the limited amount of information you provide: you've got a byte 186 (0xba) in one of the files, which means Python fails to parse the file as UTF-8.

In ISO-8859-1, 0xba is "º", so if you see this character (likely in a string) when opening files it's possible that your editor automatically infers encoding when not UTF-8, and that the file is either mis-written or mis-declared as UTF-8.

Without the exact file content as-is (copy/paste might be subject to automated transcoding from your editor) it's hard to say more. You may want to run the `file` utility on your various files to see what that says though.